# Cross Domain Migration approach

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, user-accounts, cross-domain

I need to migrate a full-fledge intranet portal running on SP13, with lots of custom made applications, into another domain. With some 5TB data.

I have gone the various blogs to get the approach but didnt find a solid one.

we planned to create a new farm in the new domain and restore the content DB of  old farm into new, and then move custom solutions one by one.

pls tell if is the right approach of doing it !

One more requirement is that the user will be able to login via their both IDs (from old domain as well as new domain) and land to same User profile (profile content and apps are customized on the bases of rights) on both logins.

How can we achieve this ? Do we need to migrate the User too or it will migrate by default!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a domain trust in place. Create a new farm as you plan on doing, and restore the content databases/service application database as applicable to the new farm.

For users, are you migrating them between domains with SID History? If so, the source account must be disabled, otherwise you break the Microsoft security model by having more than one object with the same SID.

You cannot have two users, regardless of authentication source, sharing not only permissions, but a User Profile. You need to determine which account to use. If you are migrating users to the new domain via a tool like ADMT with or without SID History, you'll need to migrate the user within SharePoint, as well. This is done via:

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Identity "i:0#.w|olddomain\username" -Web http://webUrl
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "newdomain\username" -IgnoreSID
```

Note that the `-IgnoreSID` is used anytime Claims Authentication is leveraged, regardless if you migrate SID History or not via ADMT.

If you do migrate accounts between domains with SID History, as I previously stated, you must disable one or the other accounts. The User Profile Service Sync Connections are also able to internally migrate users within SharePoint, and will not handle one connection per domain pointing to two objects that share the same SID.

Comment: I followed almost the same path for my migration. I would add a little detail: Move-SPUser should be executed for AD groups also so groups already referenced by SharePoint are correctly updated.